# VS error when debugging

Tags: visual-studio

I'm writing a C# winform application. All went well but suddenly debug won't work. I get this error message:

> Error while trying to to run project: Unable to start program [here
>   follows the path of the executable] Input or output cannot be
>   redirected because the specified file is invalid.

Here's the .sln file

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 14
VisualStudioVersion = 14.0.25123.0
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Stub", "Stub\Stub.csproj", "{C6376D67-EEEC-4AEE-B779-D743D0181636}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {C6376D67-EEEC-4AEE-B779-D743D0181636}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {C6376D67-EEEC-4AEE-B779-D743D0181636}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {C6376D67-EEEC-4AEE-B779-D743D0181636}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {C6376D67-EEEC-4AEE-B779-D743D0181636}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

I compared the project's properties with the project's properties of a dummy project and found that in my project under the **debug tab** in field **Command line options** this value:

> No Command-line

No idea where this came from, but after removing it, debugging works again.

Comment: What exactly happens? Did you change any project properties before that failure?

Comment: Not that I know of

Comment: Which version do you run?

Comment: Was using 2015. Installed 2017 with the same results, so its something to do with the project itself I think.

Comment: Could you share your .sln file? And .csproj, .csproj.user.

Comment: BTW I'm still interested how this happened to you. It would be great if you could remember the situation where this option was checked.

Answer (score 5):

Check your project's properties to contain a field **Command line options**. If it contains `No Command-line` then remove it.

Comment: Command lines containing "<" or ">" can also cause this issue

Comment: As Darren pointed out, look at the Properties > Debug > Command line arguments. If they have "<" or ">" it would cause the error.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not related to the original question, but on VS Code this can happen if you have a "<" in an argument in your launch.json when launching a .NET Core app in the debugger:

```
args: ["<something>"]
```